# Simulate fair coin toss from exponential with unknown parameter

Tags: statistics, problem-solving

Given an exponential distribution with a unknown constant $\lambda$ parameter (representing time as minutes) bounded by $\frac{1}{2}\le\lambda\le2$.

Is there a way to simulate a fair coin toss from the above distribution such that, on average, it takes less than 2 minutes and 10 seconds to obtain the outcome of the toss?

Comment: I am confused.  Is the exponential distribution the time take to obtain the outcome? It will not be the outcome of the toss itself (Heads or Tails each with probability $\frac12$).  Do you know the distribution of $\lambda$ between the bounds?

Comment: The situation is that I have access to a random phenomenon that follows an exponential distribution with unknown but bounded parameter (and the outcome of this phenomenon can be represented as time in minutes). From this setup I would like to simulate the outcome of a fair coin toss (such that on average it takes less than 2 min and 10 seconds).

Comment: For example a solution that takes less than 4 minutes on average is to wait for two events of the exponential distribution (4 minutes maximum given $\lambda=2$) and then compare the two and assign head or tail depending on which one is greater

Comment: The exact timing of the first occurrence should be good enough, no?  Random number generators are often built on some random process (like discharge times in a capacitor, and such).

Comment: How do you connect the exact timing of the first occurrence with the fair coin toss simulation though?

Comment: The practical engineering answer would be to use something like the least significant bit of the digitized time. Mathematically, that's taking a periodic function of your unknown random variable so as to "collapse" its shape to be more uniform

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor

Comment: It's possible I'm misunderstanding but: The median of $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ is $\frac{\ln 2}{\lambda}\leq 2\ln 2 \approx 1.39$. If the first event happens before then, output heads, otherwise output tails.

Comment: I agree that the first event has median upper bounded by your calculation, although I don't agree that simply taking that upper bound would give us equal probabilities for all possible values of $\lambda$

Comment: Can you elaborate on whether the "randomness extractor" concept is relevant to what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's not clear to me on how it could be applied here